# Save to Foursquare button does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, foursquare

Selecting the save button results in a darkened web page, but the Foursquare sign in popup does not show.

Tried on multiple websites mentioned on [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/buttons/savetofoursquare).

And [here](http://timeoutboston.com/thelists/124365/best-coffee-shops) is an example of it.

Observed with Firefox 16 and 17 (both Windows 7)